# Rails 3: sign_up with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I've a problem with registration of new user with devise. On my index page, I have this:

```
<%= link_to 'New User', new_user_registration_path %>
```

When I click on the link, the index page reloads. If I click on sign_up link on authentification page, there is no problem, but from the index page of an authenticated user, there is a problem. I see in the log:

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000
```

This is the [screen](http://www.freepicsup.com/?v=vvv.png). The target is an admin can create a new user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails 3: Problem with Devise](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061552/rails-3-problem-with-devise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could overwrite the Registrations Controller to sign out before sign up.

```
class Devise::RegistrationsController < ApplicationController
  […]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    #OVERWRITE
    sign_out if current_user
    #END

    resource = build_resource({})
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ render_with_scope :new }
  end

  […]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are already logged in.

Go to this url: `localhost:3000/users/sign_out`

And then click your link.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I thought it was that but there is any solution to create a new user from a logged account?

Comment: No, you can't, and that's one of the latest push by the Devise team. You should take a look at that : [Devise commit](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/4fd866d113d2de94371afe4798f242c1a453c1ab) - Description: User cannot access sign up and similar pages if he is already signed in through a cookie or token, closes #1036.